Set schedule_after_task_execution=False in Ariflow from within a dag
Is it possible to set schedule_after_task_execution=False from within a DAG? I need this functionality only for one particular DAG that has a problem with the "mini scheduler".Is it possible to be set?
I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:
default_dag_args = {
'start_date': datetime(2024,6,6),
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
'project_id': models.Variable.get('gcp_project'),
'schedule_after_task_execution': False  
}

